Apps on Windows are crashing in a domino effect while there's plenty of RAM available
Firstly, I have to say that I've been dealing with this issue for a long time and I have searched on it a lot, I have already used Windows Memory Diagnostics tool and I can say for sure that hardware failure is out of the scope of my question.
The issue seems to be with Windows memory management. I'm on Windows 11 version 23H2 OS Build 22631.3447. I use VMWare, WSL2 and Docker at all times. I stopped overclocking my RAM's (Intel XMP). After some time applications start crashing in a domino effect, so my question is how do I resolve this issue? How do I stop apps from crashing when there's still RAM available? I thought setting Paging Files as "System Managed" is the best practice in Windows.
Google Chrome crashing (Error code: Out of Memory).
Autohotkey crashing:

The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.

VSCode crashing:

The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: 'crashed', code: '-36861')

Browser extensions crashing (Metamask has crashed).
Command line applications crashing (btop says: failed to run Mem::collect()).
Sometimes even getting a BSOD, which always has something to do with ntoskrnl.exe:
I also had 2 cases of my PC just completely shutting down with no BSOD or error message and just immediately shutdown out of nowhere, first one was when I was running UNIGINE Heaven (or Valley, can't remember) when I was buying the PC in the computer shop and second one was when I was playing Far Cry 6 a few months ago.
Cygwin shows pagefile.sys usage as:
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'cd {} ; echo {}; eza -al | grep pagefile.sys' \;
./c
-a-hs  33G 12 Jul 09:26 pagefile.sys
./d
-a-hs  27G 13 Jul 22:23 pagefile.sys

Bottom shows memory usage as:

Btop4win shows memory usage as:

WSL2's htop shows:

Resource monitor shows:

Microsoft Management Console shows:

Windows page file settings:

I used to have this issue before disabling Memory Compression, I have disabled it for some time now and I can probably say it does seem BSOD crashes are less frequent now.
❯ Get-MMAgent

ApplicationLaunchPrefetching : True
ApplicationPreLaunch         : True
MaxOperationAPIFiles         : 512
MemoryCompression            : True
OperationAPI                 : True
PageCombining                : False
PSComputerName               :

❯ Disable-MMAgent -MemoryCompression

❯ Get-MMAgent

ApplicationLaunchPrefetching : True
ApplicationPreLaunch         : True
MaxOperationAPIFiles         : 512
MemoryCompression            : False
OperationAPI                 : True
PageCombining                : False
PSComputerName               :

The info above were all taken when system was unstable. Below is the Memory view of Task Manager that I took when system was stable:

Update: I have been dealing with this for months, I have tested disabling things like Memory Compression, Intel XMP, fiddling with page file settings, testing RAM with Windows Memory Diagnostics, etc. I want to know, is this crashing domino effect related to RAM and page file and my C drive not having enough space or is my 13600k is one of the few cases that has been hit by Intel microcode fiasco? I recently extended my C drive and now it has a lot of free space for page file. Purchased a new SSD and enabled page file on it. Changed all page file settings so that they are all System managed.
The reason I have Memory Compression disabled is because it uses a lot of RAM, and if the Memory Compression process crashes the whole system crashes. I have much better stability with Memory Compression and XMP disabled.
The reason why I have "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives" disabled is because I want to enable it on only my SSD's. And the reason why I have it enabled on more than one drive is that my C drive did not have enough free space. Is it best to have page file on only one drive or have the "Automatically... " option enabled?
I thought WSL2 was the reason for my RAM issues, sometimes when VScode crashes, I just shutdown WSL2, restart VSCode and things go normally again, so I'm still not sure what's the cause of all of this.
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4166

Why do you have a page file on more than just the system file? Why do you not have "Automatically manage .." selected? Why are you disabling memory compression if you are fighting a page file or virtual memory problem?

You don't have a "lot of free RAM", you are operating pretty close to your commit limit at 123 of 128GB. You may well have some overheads or virtual memory fragmentation eating the rest.

As I said I have enough RAM, the issue as I figured out was due to 13th/14th gen Intel CPU microcode issues leading to apps crashing in a domino effect, I also thought WSL2 was the culprit, and just when VSCode starts acting up, I would just shut down WSL2 and restart it and the PC would work normally. If you opened this question I would like to add this as an answer. @Mokubai

Something on your system is leaking memory. You must find out what it is. Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager’s Performance → Memory view. I suggest removing all the error screenshots, they aren’t relevant IMHO.

@DanielB Hello, I updated the question and added a lot more important detail. Please have a look at it thank you very much.

Beyond finding the source of your memory leaks, have you tried replacing your system memory chips? Accepting this has been going on as long as you say it has, you really should have either fully reinstalled your OS and then begun replacing hardware in your diagnostic efforts by now.

@music2myear Hello, this PC cost me 6 months salary of my full time job while studying for a Computer Science master's degree, but you are absolutely right, testing CPU/RAM sticks are important, they are my last resort, but the system is working from day to day, and I'm not behind my schedules, if I reinstall the OS or start spending on hardware however, things will get more stressful and it is already painfully stressful. I got this PC just for the degree, I was fine on my laptop...

While I understand that a reinstall is difficult, dealing with the sorts of frustration and unease you've documented here over months of time adds up to a significant amount of time as well. What the PC costs is largely immaterial to diagnosing the issues.

So, yes, you definitely have both a paged and non-paged pool leak. Depending on your actual workload you also have a “regular” memory leak. You could try and sort processes (under “Details”) in Task Manager by “Commit size” (you may have to enable this column first). Check if there’s anything with humongous values, especially compared to the “Memory (active)” column. // All of these are software problems, not hardware problems.

@DanielB Yes that would be WSl2 (vmmemWSL) with Memory (active private working set) of 4,000,000 K and Commit size of 25,000,000 K.
